# Grails Imprimir Modal sólo una vez términos y condiciones

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Grails 2.4.3 y pues ya cuenta con un Modal donde se muestran los términos y condiciones de uso y el contrato de usuario.

Deseo que este Modal sólo se imprima una sóla vez por sesión.

Si me dan alguna idea lo agradecería.

```
<g:if test="${session.acuerdoUsuario==true}">
  <asset:script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(acuerdoUsuario){
    ${session.setAttribute("acuerdoUsuario", false)};
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#terminosYCondicionesModal').modal('show');
            }, 300);

        })
  </asset:script>
</g:if>
```

Comment: Debes ser más específico, porque las preguntas basadas en opiniones van en contra de la política de la comunidad. Usa Google para buscar las ideas que quieres y si tienes un error al implementarla, pide ayuda aquí. Consulta esta guía http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve en especial la sección **Verificable**.

Answer (score 0):

Yo NO te recomendaría agregar lógica del lado del servidor para resolver lo que querés. Tu problema puede ser solucionado simplemente utilizando javascript. Una solución que te sugiero es utilizar el storage del browser que "vive durante la sesión" (mas info [aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp))

Haría algo como lo siguiente:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         if (!window.sessionStorage.disableModal) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#terminosYCondicionesModal').modal('show');
                window.sessionStorage.disableModal = true;
            }, 300);
         }
      })
```

En el código anterior se utiliza el storage de la sesión mediante `window.sessionStorage`. Esta información se eliminará cuando se cierre el browser y será solo será almacenada para cada sesión.

Espero sirva. Saludos